# Error when trying to extract values from a Json Object C#

Tags: c#, json, object, json.net

I have a Json string like below and this is only a small snippet. The number in quotation marks is a Unix Time which i will need to use to iterate over each object.

```
{
  "result": {
    "1534860000": [
      "1534860000",
      19,
      41
    ],
    "1534863600": [
      "1534863600",
      11,
      16
    ],
    "1534867200": [
      "1534867200",
      2,
      5
    ]
  }
}
```

But when I attempt to extract the data in the arrays I get an error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cannot access child value on Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty.'

Code:

```
JObject jsonObj = JObject.Parse(response);

string unixTime = Helpers.ConvertToUnix(yesterday.AddHours(hour)).ToString();

foreach (var obj in jsonObj["result"])
{      
    var array = obj[unixTime]; //here is where the error occurs
}
```

Anyone able to shed some light on what I am missing?

Comment: In this particular instance, the unix time is exactly the same as the first entry of the json e.g. "1534860000"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we simplify your example code a little to remove the `unixTime` element (let's just hardcode it for now), we end up with this:

```
JObject jsonObj = JObject.Parse(response);
string unixTime = "1534860000";
```

At this stage, we have `jsonObj` which refers to the root of the JSON object and has a single property of `result`. Repeating your `foreach` here for context:

```
foreach (var obj in jsonObj["result"])
{
    var array = obj[unixTime]; //here is where the error occurs
}
```

You end up with `obj` referring to the JSON path of `result.1534860000`. The problem is you're then looking for a property `1534860000` at *this* JSON path (`result.1534860000.1534860000`), which does not exist.

You can just get the value directly, like so:

```
var array = obj["result"][unixTime]
```

Of course, this requires some error-checking for ensuring the path exists, etc, but it demonstrates the point.

Answer (score 0):

After some help from Kirk Larkin I thought I would post a code snippet up.

```
JObject jsonObj = JObject.Parse(response);

int hour = 0;
string unixTime = Helpers.ConvertToUnix(yesterday.AddHours(hour)).ToString();

var array = jsonObj["result"][unixTime];
```

It now returns the contents of the array.